# display image in unordered list method using html helper cake

Tags: cakephp-2.3

Hi what im asking I suppose is quite straight forward, just having problems displaying images in the HTML helper for cakePHP im trying to use the nested array method in cake to arrange the images nicely but keeps giving this error 'Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ')' in C:\wamp\www\end\app\View\Layouts\default.ctp on line 50' heres the code if someone can help me out will be deeply appreciated.
PS: im using cake 2.3.6.

```
    <?php echo $this->Html->image('logo.png', array('alt' => 'logo image'));?>
   <?php $list = array(
    'echo $this->Html->image('cloud.png', array('alt' => 'logo image'))' => array(
    'echo $this->Html->image('heart.png', array('alt' => 'logo image'))' => array(
    'echo $this->Html->image('email.png', array('alt' => 'logo image'))',
    'echo $this->Html->image('profile.png', array('alt' => 'logo image'))',
    'echo $this->Html->image('logo.png', array('alt' => 'logo image'))', 

    echo $this->Html->nestedList($list);

   ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code syntax is wrong,

```
$list = array(
             $this->Html->image('cloud.png', array('alt' => 'logo image')) =>
             array(
                  $this->Html->image('heart.png', array('alt' => 'logo image')) => 
                        array(
                            $this->Html->image('email.png', array('alt' => 'logo image')),
                            $this->Html->image('profile.png', array('alt' => 'logo image')),
                            $this->Html->image('logo.png', array('alt' => 'logo image'))
                            )
                  )
             );
```

You cannot use echo inside the array.

Alternatively you can create your own helper and method, as mentioned below:

send only image name array to the helper and in return get name and alt tags in desired order then loop them as shown below:

```
 $list = array('cloud.png','heart.png','email.png','profile.png','logo.png'); 

        $arragedList =  $this->MyHelper->nestedList($list);
        foreach($arragedList as $arrangedImages){
             echo $this->Html->image($$arrangedImages['imageName'], 
                               array('alt' =>$$arrangedImages['altTag']));
        }
```

Hope it will help!

Comment: hi sorry to bother u again but some reason theres a warning saying 'Invalid argument supplied for foreach() [APP\View\Layouts\default.ctp, line 52]' i'm a bit new to cake so sorry.

Comment: Have you tries the first solution? for alternative method you have to create your own helper and method.

Comment: Do u mean that i have to create a separate helper class in the helper folder and then write this code 'public $MyHelper = array('Html', 'image'); is that right and what else do i need to do?

Comment: Yes you have to create your own helper class and create one method inside that helper which will sort or order your images and returns the correct array, then in the view file you have to use the above code.

Comment: hi - just wanted to know if it is ok if you can have my skype because, im running into a lot of problems with this application and like i said before im quite new to cake bless.                     skype name: cartfredri